# How to use the <form method=GET> in WP

Tags: forms

I have a page that shows a products list. I need that when a user click on a product image a product page is shown.
If I use this in my form:

```
$retval .= '<form method=post action="'. str_replace( '%7E', '~', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']).'">';
```

and

```
$retval .= '<input type="hidden" name="fcf_getClubDetails" value="Y">';
```

I can then catch the action using

```
 if($_POST['fcf_getProdDetails'] == 'Y') {
```

When i try to switch to the GET method, just changing POST to GET does not work.
I see the parameter are passed to the URL but I don't know how to set the correct URL, because I'm sent back to the home page.
Thanks

Comment: You changed `post` to `get` in both locations? What sends you back to the home page, exactly?

Comment: sounds like your action isn't set correctly. Can you echo `'. str_replace( '%7E', '~', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']).'`and see if it is what you wanted? You should just be able to change post to get. Don't forget to change `method=post`to `method=GET`

Comment: The echo result of that function is /mySite/?page_id=4352. I find that URL in the browser. If I use GET instead (on both FORM and IF stmt, the IF does not return true (the echo is after the IF stmt) and the URL is directed to http://localhost/mySite/?fcf_getClubDetails=Y&myplugin_submit_button=GO